# jquery how to passi a complex url as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass a link as a url parameter :-e

mywebsite.com?urlparam=anotherhost.com?somevar=var&anothervar=var2

how would I go about creating this in jquery

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var _URL = encodeURIComponent("anotherhost.com?somevar=var&anothervar=var2");
//result: anotherhost.com%3Fsomevar%3Dvar%26anothervar%3Dvar2
```

to encode the url for use it as a url param.

Than call the new url with:

```
location.href = "mywebsite.com?urlparam="+ _URL;
//result:"mywebsite.com?urlparam=anotherhost.com%3Fsomevar%3Dvar%26anothervar%3Dvar2"
```

this reload the page with new URL.

**Enjoy.**